# Nagios nrpe command fails but local command works

Tags: nrpe

I'm using a custom script to check physical memory.
https://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=3329&cf_id=24

(i added the performance data)

Locally run with this:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_custom_memory.sh
```

output:

> OK - 30405 MB (96%) Free Memory | total=31513MB used=1108MB

When I run it from the nagios server with this command (hid actual IP for security reasons):

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -t 60 -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -c check_custom_memory.sh -a 10 5
```

output:

> CRITICAL - 30405 MB (%) Free Memory | total=31513MB used=1108MB

It seems that the check_nrpe is excluding the % value.  This happens only on this server and not my other servers.  All other checks run fine.  Any other nrpe check to the remote server works fine too.  It seems to be just this one check.  It makes me think it's the script but it works for other servers and locally, so i'm at a loss.

the /tmp/memcalc file has 666 permissions and owned by nrpe on the remote server, and I can see it's being written like it should when run locally.  When running with check_nrpe, the file is not being accessed or written.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the issue.  Seems like it has something to do with selinux running.  Normally we don't use it but this server has it running.  It seems to stop access to writing to the file that's created in the /tmp directory to calculate the percentage of free memory.

As a result.  I just rewrote the script to not use a temp file and to calculate the percentage using simple math and not being accurate (which is fine).